# Missing Return Statement Compilation Error

Tags: java

Errors with missing return statement. Anyone have any idea what's wrong with the code?

```
import java.text.*;
public class Sentence {
    private String text;
    public Sentence(String str) {
        str = text;
    }
    public boolean isPalindrome() {
        int length = text.length();
        for(int n = 0;n <= length/2;n++) {
            char letterFromFront = text.charAt(n);
            char letterFromBack = text.charAt(length);
            if(letterFromFront == letterFromBack) {
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Elaborate more by posting your error messages

Comment: Its possible that function never returns anything (ie - the compiler can't be sure at compile time that your for loop even gets executed).  I think you also have a logic error.  IE - that function will return true for the input `asdfsdfa` because on the first loop a == a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its complaining because there won't be any return if it doesn't enter in the `for` loop.

**Please add a `return` statement after `for` loop.**

Also please note: `n++` in your `for` loop is a **dead code** as your returning in the first iteration itself.

Answer (score 1):

> anyone have any idea what's wrong with the code?

Exactly what it says.

Put it this way: what do you think this is going to return if the string is empty? (In fact, it will throw an exception because you probably want your upper bound to be exclusive rather than inclusive, but fundamentally you need to consider the case where it never goes into the body of the loop.)

There are other things wrong with this code, mind you:

- `text.charAt(length)` is going to throw an exception, always
- Did you *really* mean to always return in the first iteration? That would suggest that xabcx is a palindrome... (Hint: you can only validly return `true` when you've finished the loop...)

Comment: Actually in that case it will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException I believe ;-)

Comment: @assylias: Oops, I hadn't noticed that the loop upper bound is *inclusive*. Ick!

Answer (score 1):

If `length` is `-2` for example (which admittedly can't happen), your loop will never run and you will not return anything.

You need to add a return statement after the loop to satisfy the compiler, or even better before your loop, check if length is `>1` and return true/false if not.

There are other issues in your code but that is the reason for the compiler error.

Comment: The value of `-1` will not be sufficient, because `-1/2` is zero. You need a string with even fewer characters ;-)

Comment: This code is surprisingly difficult to apprehend it seems ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not take consideration of the case when n is not less than or equal to `length/2` .

I suppose that in case if it is not palindrome which means whatever happens ,you want to return false.

```
public class Sentence {
    private String text;
    public Sentence(String str) {
        str = text;
    }
    public boolean isPalindrome() {
        boolean value = false;
        int length = text.length();
        for(int n = 0;n <= length/2;n++) {
            char letterFromFront = text.charAt(n);
            char letterFromBack = text.charAt(length);
            if(letterFromFront == letterFromBack) {
                value = true;
            }else {
                value = false;
            }
        }
       return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `return false` should be placed after the loop, otherwise it runs always once

```
public boolean isPalindrome() {
    int length = text.length();
    for(int n = 0;n <= length/2;n++) {
        char letterFromFront = text.charAt(n);
        char letterFromBack = text.charAt(length);
        if(letterFromFront == letterFromBack) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove return statment from else clause and move before the end of loop. So if number is palindrome it falls in if clause and returns true and if not it returns false. 
Theoratically you code is right but the compiler doesnt see it this way.